# How to render list items in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [List](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list) to render the data vertically. Docs suggests a way  for hardcoded data but I have data in an array.

Docs have this example :

```
<MobileTearSheet>
  <List>
    <ListItem primaryText="Inbox" leftIcon={<ContentInbox />} />
    <ListItem primaryText="Starred" leftIcon={<ActionGrade />} />
    <ListItem primaryText="Sent mail" leftIcon={<ContentSend />} />
    <ListItem primaryText="Drafts" leftIcon={<ContentDrafts />} />
    <ListItem primaryText="Inbox" leftIcon={<ContentInbox />} />
  </List>
  <Divider />
  <List>
    <ListItem primaryText="All mail" rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} />
    <ListItem primaryText="Trash" rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} />
    <ListItem primaryText="Spam" rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} />
    <ListItem primaryText="Follow up" rightIcon={<ActionInfo />} />
  </List>
</MobileTearSheet>
```

I have `todos` array which I want to render in a `ListItem`. Can anyone suggest me how to do ?

```
this.state = {
  open: false,
  todos: [],
  notetext: ""
};
```

I am adding elements in an array as below:

```
todos.push({
  id: todos.length,
  text: this.state.notetext,
  completed: false
});
```

Comment: So you want to render each todo in a list item? You should use the Array object's ```map``` function to iterate over the array and create new ListItems that are passed each todo to their props.

Comment: text of todos items you want as primaryText ? what about the right icon?

Comment: @MayankShukla I don't need right icon, just a todos items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` to iterate the `todos` array, then for each item of the `array` create a `ListItem` element.

Write it like this:

```
_renderTodos(){
    return this.state.todos.map(el => {
        return <ListItem primaryText={el.text} key={el.id}/>
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <MobileTearSheet>
            <List>
                {this._renderTodos()}
            </List>
        </MobileTearSheet>
    )
}
```

Check this snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
    
     constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
           a: [1,2,3,4]
        }
     }
  
     _renderItems(){
         return this.state.a.map(el => <p>{el}</p>)
     }
     
     render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this._renderItems()}
            </div>            
        )
     }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: He'll have to bind this to ```_renderTodos``` if he's using ES6 classes.

Comment: @MichaelLyons not required, i am simply calling that method, calling method will always the the reference of object from where it get called.

Comment: Well you're referencing ```this.state.todos``` from within the method, the context will have to be bound.

Comment: @MichaelLyons run that code, it will work without any error, binding of a simply called method is not required :)

Comment: Thanks. Is this rule to use _ before function name ?

Comment: no this is not a rule, it's just a way of writing only, i used to use **_** to differentiate between custom defined function and predefined lib functions.

Comment: @MayankShukla Checked the code, learned something. I guess I never really simply call methods, in this format. Voted as answer.

Comment: @MayankShukla I have `handleChange`, would you add underscore before it `handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
`

Comment: i always use _ to all functions that i defined, so yes i will use **_** like this:  `_handleChange(event) { this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }); }`

Comment: @MichaelLyons glad, it helped you :)

Comment: @MayankShukla It is displaying like this http://imgur.com/a/W5uT7 I am not sure why there is a line ? Is it by default in `List` ? and why no-image icon at the bottom-left ?

Comment: @Williams that line is by the default style of material-ui list, you can remove that by using css properties padding, margin and border. not sure about the image it should not come. Check your code are you using image at any place ?

Comment: @MayankShukla I don't have image at any place in my code. Can you try this lib ? Is it only for me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146557/discussion-between-williams-and-mayank-shukla).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate on your array with something like that:

```
_buildItem(item, index) {
    return <ListItem key={index} primaryText={item.text}/>
}

render() { return (
    <List>
        {this.state.todos.map(this._buildItem)}
    </List>
)}
```

Comment: well an answer poped meanwhile, and its almost the same xD